# Parameters repeated while using NSURL to create new post on rails server using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, json, nsurlrequest

My issue is that when i POST to a rails server to create a new post using the following code from the iphone simulator, the parameters are sent twice.

```
NSDictionary *thestuff = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         titleIs, @"title", 
                         descIs, @"description", nil];
NSString *tojson = [thestuff JSONRepresentation];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request addValue:@"form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Disposition"];
[request setHTTPBody:[tojson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

Assuming NSString tojson contains this :

```
    {"title":"wwd","description":"wwwwwww"}
```

when i send the request, the rails server shows parameters as:

```
Processing by PostsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"title"=>"wwd", "description"=>"wwwwwww", "post"=>{"title"=>"wwd", "description"=>"wwwwwww"}}
```

as you can see, the title and description are sent twice according to this. Is there a way to fix this and does this pose a security issue if i use Post to post username and password?
The post is created as I want without any issues but i really want to fix this double parameter post.

Comment: It appears that your problem is with your backend, not with your iOS code.

Comment: Well the server was made using scaffolding thats in Ruby on Rails. Also when i create a post using the webpage for creating new posts, this does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this expected behavior which can be changed depending on your needs. This is enabled by a property called `ParamsWrapper` in `ActionController` and you can read the [documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

It is enabled default to make it easier to give wrapped parameters to `Create` and `Update` actions on ActiveRecord objects.

You can disable this by changing it in

config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb

```
wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
```

to false

```
wrap_parameters false
```

read about other option available on [ruby docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper/ClassMethods.html)